# Numpy 300 dimensional array is getting converted to 150 dimension after to bytes and from buffer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I came across this weird behaviour and I have no clue what is wrong. If I declare a numpy array with float32 and the convert it to bytes and then back to numpy then it goes from 300 to 150. I am just trying to convert the first item in a numpy array to bytes and then back to numpy later on

```
x = np.random.randn(200, 300)
x = np.array(x, dtype='float32')
print(x.shape)
y = np.frombuffer(x[0].tobytes())
print(y.shape)
```

Output:

```
(200, 300)
(150,)
```

Does anyone know whats going on ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because default `dtype` for `np.frombuffer` is `float` which is most likely `'float64'`. You want

```
y = np.frombuffer(x[0].tobytes(), dtype=x.dtype)
```

Comment: Is there are a better way to convert numpy arrays to bytes and then convert them back up without having to worry about which type of float is ? I am trying to save numpy arrays in redis btw

Comment: The `tobytes()` does not record any information about the array dtype or shape.  The `np.save` format add a header block with this kind of information.